# gray matter segmentation in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am searching for segmenting gray matter from a T1 weighted brain MRI scan. But I could not get the correct tutorial to follow it. Please suggest me an algorithm  that works better and accurately to segment the gray matter alone from the T1 wieghted MRI scan image. There are several tools to segment gray matter in matlab but I need algorithm to segment the gray matter. Please suggest me the algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?  SPM does a good job of segmentation and the MATLAB source code is freely available: http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/

You can examine the algorithm that is used and customize it for your own purposes if you wish.  It produces probabilistic maps of gray matter, white matter, and csf that you can use in subsequent analyses.  There are also a variety of options to complete the segmentation in both normalized and native space.  I highly recommend it as a place to get started, and then you can branch off from there depending on your needs.

Comment: Sir I used it and saw the results but the situation is that I need to use it as a function. For example if we apply Kmeans algorithm there is a function in matlab similarly I need to use this as a code in matlab but not with the help of this tool.

Comment: Can you help me to use the SPM code as a function in matlab.

Comment: With a bit of work you could certainly use it as a callable function.  This would involve looking over the SPM code, finding the relevant parts, and then dropping them into your own MATLAB script.  The spm_preproc.m script would be a good place to start.  If all you need to do is segment T1 anatomical images, then using the SPM batch processing mode might be easier.  You can pass in the path to your image along with whatever options you want to set, execute the job, and you end up with segmented images.

Comment: You might check MATLAB Central as well. There seem to be a nice collection of scripts that you could integrate with your own program, such as this one: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4879-mri-brain-segmentation

Comment: Thanks for telling me where to start. I will surely try it and tell the sequence which suits for the better result. If you can find the sequence which I should follow please notify me by commenting. Thank you.